# Search throws E363: pattern uses more memory than 'maxmempattern'

Tags: search

I ran a `/.*stem\&.*sun` in vim terminal.

It prompted this error without throwing me any search result.

```
E363: pattern uses more memory than 'maxmempattern'                               
E385: search hit BOTTOM without match for: .*stem\&.*sun
```

Any solution ?

I am learning to search multiple words in a sentence in vim in any order. I tried:

```
/word1.*word2\|word2.*word1
```

This works, but i am looking for a more convenient way to do it because eventually I will have to look for  way to search for 3 (or more) words in a sentence in any order.

Comment: You don't have enough memory allocated for a complicated and/or inefficient regex search. See `:h 'maxmempattern'`. (Searching for the error message would have taken you to the same place: `:h E363`)

Comment: I see, It said the search pattern is too complex..  that would meant the ''/.*stem&.*sun'' to search the 2 words in any order in a sentence is totally no no.

Comment: /(?i)(?:test.*long|long.*test)/     <---this also don't work

Comment: Can you increase `'maxmempattern'`? If it doesn't need much more mem then maybe that's the easiest way to go. The default is only 1MB.

Comment: what is the highest possible i can increase it ? The help :h E363 didn't show how to increase the search memory limit. There is statement "max value is about 2000000. use this to work without a limit" but it never mention how and where to edit that value

Comment: I can't digest the help text.. too vague for me..But i think it says it is located in "swapfile" ?? no location...

Comment: It's a regular Vim setting. Put it in your vimrc...at least for now. Try something far less than the max...increase the default by some multiple.

Comment: Can you pls show me the  syntax and example how to write it into vimrc ?

Comment: :set maxmempattern=5000    i saw this in google.. is that correct ?  i just need to change the value  . got it changed.

Comment: @andrew_ysk If that solve your issue please post an answer and mark it as accepted so that future reader will know it worked for you.

Comment: That other pattern in the comments looks like PCRE, which is not compatible with vim’s patterns

Comment: One way to avoid this is to do it incrementally with `:vimgrep` and `:Cfilter`. e.g. `:vimgrep /stem/ %` then `:packadd cfilter` & `:Cfilter /sun/`. Simply continue adding `:Cfilter`'s patterns as needed. Use quickfix command to move between lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment to the original question, a workaround in an active editing session is:

```
:set maxmempattern=5000
```

Or just `set mmp=5000` in your `.vimrc` to make it permanent. The value of `5000` is arbitrary and may not be enough. The highest value as of the time of this writing is about `2000000`, which effectively means "no limit".

It should be noted that this is just a workaround: the underlying search, which may be found in separate file like a syntax highlighting definition, should be fixed to have a more efficient pattern.